# SSH accepts key but SSHFS doesn't

Tags: networking, server, ssh

From my mac, I can ssh to an ubuntu machine without a problem.

The key is under my `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

When I try to sshfs to the same ip i get:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:klJ1Y+1p8LdZuhukPrdpIOlolC05sX628n9owaM4DZY.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
ECDSA host key for xx.xx.xx.xx has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
remote host has disconnected
```

The key mentioned on the log is not the one I have on `known_hosts` for this IP, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mounting `sshfs` from  `root` or using `sudo`, while `ssh` is called with your normal user.

So `sshfs` Host key is not in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, but `/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Remove line 4 of that file and it will work:

```
sudo sed -i '4d' /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Alternatively, run `sshfs` with your normal user without `sudo`.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, except that the symptom was "remote host has disconnected". Running `sshfs` from the client without `sudo` fixed it.

Comment: I just spent like 30 minutes trying to solve that 'remote host has disconnected.' Only to find your comment and realize that because I was using sudo it wasn't using the right account for paths and permissions. Thanks for solving my problem pLumo.